# 'cannot convert type system web ui webcontrols listitem' to my class

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to get an item from a `listbox` and take it as a `car` item.

I want to take the `tempcar` , take out its values and add them to a session state value where I can edit the values in on a different page.

At the moment I'm using this recycled code from an application but it doesn't seem to work on webforms due to the following issue 
*cannot convert type system web ui webcontrols listitem to car*

```
  if (lbxCars.SelectedItem != null)
  {
      car tempCar = lbxCars.SelectedItem as car;    
  }
```

Any help would be widely appreciated. Also I understand what I'm doing is clunky but it's meant to show of functionality.

Thanks

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
    private static string tableName = "CarTable";
    private static string car_1 = "05-Rn-1964";
    private static string car_2 = "05-Rn-1965";
    private static string car_3 = "05-Rn-1966";
    List<car> cars = new List<car>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table CarTable = Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTable(client, tableName);
    GetItemOperationConfig config = new GetItemOperationConfig
    {
        AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "Reg", "Manufactor", "Year", "Problems" },
        ConsistentRead = true
    };
    Document doc1 = CarTable.GetItem(car_1, config);
    Document doc2 = CarTable.GetItem(car_2, config);
    Document doc3 = CarTable.GetItem(car_3, config);

    string Reg1 = doc1["Reg"].AsString();
    string Manufactor1 = doc1["Manufactor"].AsString();
    string Year1 = doc1["Year"].AsString();
    string Problems1 = doc1["Problems"].AsString();

    string Reg2 = doc2["Reg"].AsString();
    string Manufactor2 = doc2["Manufactor"].AsString();
    string Year2 = doc2["Year"].AsString();
    string Problems2 = doc2["Problems"].AsString();

    string Reg3 = doc3["Reg"].AsString();
    string Manufactor3 = doc3["Manufactor"].AsString();
    string Year3 = doc3["Year"].AsString();
    string Problems3 = doc3["Problems"].AsString();




    car car1 = new car(Reg1, Manufactor1, Year1, Problems1);
    car car2 = new car(Reg2, Manufactor2, Year2, Problems2);
    car car3 = new car(Reg3, Manufactor3, Year3, Problems3);
    cars.Add(car1);
    cars.Add(car2);
    cars.Add(car3);







    lbxCars.DataSource = cars;
    lbxCars.DataBind();

}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("Default.aspx", true);
}

protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("EditCar.aspx", true);
}

protected void LinkButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("NewCar.aspx", true);
}

protected void LinkButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("ViewDataBase.aspx", true);
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("EditCar.aspx", true);
}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbxCars.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        //car tempCar = lbxCars.SelectedItem as car;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, that's a `ListItem`, not a `car`.

Comment: I'm aware of that , i'm asking is there any way to take the list item and convert it into a type car? because it is populated by a list of cars.

Comment: Can you show how you populate the listbox? Don't they just have `Text` and `Value` properties?

Comment: You have to create or lookup the correct `car` with the value of `lbxCars.SelectedValue`

Comment: it's updated now with all the code. So if i were to populate the list without hardcoding it (which i realise i have at the moment) , i wouldn't be able to select a 'car' on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, where ID is the property you're using for the SelectedValue in your listbox.

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbxCars.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        var tempCar = cars.Any(e=>e.ID==lbxCars.SelectedValue );
    }
}
```